# old ActionBar style with AppCompat-v7 21

Tags: android, android-appcompat

I use one of libraries, which needs API 21. After I changed "compile with" to 21, I needed to rewrite my ActionBar to show proper color and menu icon (the new one with animation from sticks to arrow). Is there any way to make the style of my ActionBar like in older APIs with old height and old menu icon and it's animation?
EDIT:
Here is my old ActionBar:
[image]
Then after "compile with: 21":
[image]
The logo is gone, the menu icon is no more on the left edge
Then I done some stuff to fix it:
[image]
Now is the ActionBar exactly for v7 21, but I need my old ActionBar like on the screenshot 1.

Comment: Why would you upgrade a library to use old code? and no the resources have changed.

Comment: I mean, I need to compile with API 21 because of one of libraries that I use. But I also need my old ActionBar like in API 19.

Comment: AppCompat-v7r21.0.3 is the latest. This comes with the new ToolBar but you can still use the ActionBar. The styling has changed. You need to post code(styles.xml) etc and possibly a picture.